# Is it possible to modify notifications using the NotificationListenerService?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is this strictly a read-only thing or would I be able to actually modify the title/text/image of any of the current notifications on the device?  If so how would I do this? I went through the documentation and couldn't find an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only notifications you can modify are ones that your apps create. The NLS is for monitoring events only. Even with reflection you will get Permission errors, etc.

The only "work around" is a modded AOSP install or signing your app as "system" (which is a custom install solution also, unless you intend to have your apps ship with the device from the manufacturer / carrier).